# jstree and user acces to node

Tags: jquery, jstree

My problem is that I would like to show user the full tree to the element / elements (node / nodes) to which it has access.
For example, I have a tree like this:

[screen1](http://img822.imageshack.us/img822/1517/screen1i.gif)

I have a database table with fields: user_id, node_id
This table stores the users access to nodes.

For example I have in this table the following values:

user_id || node_id

1       || 9

1       || 10

I want that user to view the full tree of nodes to whose it has access, that is:

[screen2](http://img694.imageshack.us/img694/1065/screen2p.gif)

If I can not do it that way, I have another solution.
Display the whole tree, and when the node is selected by the user to check whether he has access to it. But I would like to avoid this solution and did not show the user nodes to which it has no access.

Comment: What is the question?  Are you asking how to implement this?  Have you tried implementing something and are having a specific problem?

Comment: My problem (question) is the following.
How to display user the nodes to which it has access, but with the overriding nodes that node.

Answer (score 0):

the most "safe" way is probably loading the tree with json, so you can handle authorization on the controller/backend side of you application

have a look at the jsTree [JSON_data_plugin](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/json_data)

Comment: Example, which is attached to jstree, returns the data in json format.
But I do not know how the side of php / mysql to filter out unnecessary nodes (those for which the user has no access) and view those to which it has access in the form of the whole tree.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the PHP example code (index.html) you will see this when setting up the JSON data:

```
"data" : function (n) { 
// the result is fed to the AJAX request `data` option
return { 
    "operation" : "get_children", 
    "id" : n.attr ? n.attr("id").replace("node_","") : 1 
};
```

Set the number `1` in the `id` attributes to change the root folder in the tree.

For each of your users create a new row in the database and then use that id number as the root folder.

Then just change the `1` in the `id` attributes to a variable and pass in your users root id.